# What programming languages and databases are suported by Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have previous experience in using Ethereum and Solidity, but now I want to try writing smart contracts for Hyperledger.

I have few considerations:

First one is regarding supported databases. According to their documentation (http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ledger.html) they use LevelDB for storing contract data and CouchDB support is still in beta. Does anyone have any experience using CouchDB in Hyperledger?

Second, I see that Go is mostly used for the specification of smart contracts, but they have support for Java too. Is Java still in beta too, and is there support for any other programming language?

Also, what operating system do you suggest for production server running Hyperledger?

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Java still in beta too, and is there support for any other
>   programming language?

Hyperledger V1.0 doesn't support Java Chaincode.
There will be support for it in the future.
You can ask around in https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric for ETAs.

There is also a work in progress to have node.js support.

> Also, what operating system do you suggest for production server
>   running Hyperledger?

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS works well

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone have any experience using CouchDB in Hyperledger?

Yes, CouchDB works well if your data is modeled as JSON and you would like to query the content of the data.  The default goleveldb state database only supports key-based queries.

Comment: Can you please provide some links related to CouschDB setup?

Comment: CouchDB is provided by Fabric as a preconfigured docker image. Here are links showing the docker-compose setup to leverage CouchDB docker container, as well as a sample walking through the usage.  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/first-network/docker-compose-couch.yaml  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#using-couchdb

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Hyperleger Composer](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/) that helps you create blockchain applications on Hyperledger Fabric quite easy. (It works better with Ubuntu).

It has is own [Modeling Language](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/cto_language.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger initially was build using **Go** language.

the aim of the hyperledger team is to support as many languages as possible. currently the hyperledger composer( tool for developing blockchain application) supports javascript for defining the assets, transactions and chaincode.

the transactions log, state data and backed by **Level DB** and **Couch DB**

**Note :**

> LevelDB and CouchDB are fully integrated in fabric framework,
>   currently you can't replace them with other database

Chaincode runs in a secured Docker container, the chaincode (aka smart-contract)can be programmed in **Go**,**Node**,**Java** currently Go is stable and fully supported language.

considering the operating system i have tested the fabric network running on Microsoft Azure platform where created a image of ubuntu 16.04 and installed Fabric framework.till now got no issue on it.