# Does the language in which the hyperledger's chaincode is written matter?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to develop a chaincode in hyperledger. I know that the chaincode cab be developed in either java,go or node js. My question is does it matter which language I am developing the chaincode in?

Comment: You may refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343169/what-programming-languages-and-databases-are-suported-by-hyperledger-fabric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering which language to write chaincode in I've typically seen orgs ask themselves the following questions:

- Which language has the most mature SDK/support?
- Which language has the most developer interest/ease of hiring?
- Which language provides the most safety?

The last one is often overlooked but is, in my opinion, one of the most crucial when considering that bugs in chaincode are often much more important than bugs in typical code! Remember that the output of the chaincode is inscribed for all time within the ledger, and that fixing the outputs of bad chaincode can be a costly process.

Considering those questions, you can evaluate the three languages (go, nodejs, java) chaincode supports as follows:

- **Golang** has by far the most mature SDK/support. Fabric is written in Go and considers Go a first-class citizen in all tangential projects; it is therefore often the first considered and most updated language when it comes to Fabric support.
- **NodeJS** is probably easiest to find talent for and is already a widely popular language, meaning chaincode will typically be most accessible when written in NodeJS. The first developed and most popular Fabric SDK (non-chaincode) is the nodejs one so these go together very well. Of course, **Java** probably has just as many if not more available developers, but I'm counting it second here as it is much less supported.
- **Golang** and **Java** are both strongly typed languages and provide the guarantees such languages bring. Java also brings with it many years of production experience and safety. Those both win out when it comes to language safety over a dynamically-typed, JIT-compiled language like nodejs.

TL;DR: Golang has strong safety guarantees and is most widely supported, NodeJS is easier to write and easier to find developers for, Java is a tough sell

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using GoLang as it is a highly efficient and powerful language in terms of performance and scalability.